# Can I parameterize labels and properties on CREATE or SET? (REST and transaction)

Tags: rest, parameters, neo4j, cypher, label

I have a query

```
1. CREATE (a:%1$s {props}), (b:%2$s {props2}), (b)-[:%3$s {relProps}]->(a)
2. MATCH (a:%1$s { value:{value} })-[:%2$s]->(b) WHERE (b:%3$s) SET (b {props})
```

I'm using underscore.string to allow string format but would love to just stick with parameters.

Is it possible to parameterize labels such as

```
{ 
  "query": CREATE (a:{label} {props}),
  "params": {
    "label":"SomeLabel",
    "props":{....}
  }
}
```

and is it also possible to parameterize properties on a SET?

```
{
  "query": "MATCH ..... SET (node {props})"
  "params": {
    "props":{
      "prop1:":"Property Name",
      .... 
    }
  }
}
```

Also is there a way to parameterize on a "MERGE"? it gives me 'Parameter maps cannot be used in MERGE patterns (use a literal map instead, eg. "{id: {param}.id}")'

EDIT: what about parameterizing where clause?

```
MATCH (:Identity%1$s {nodeId:{nodeId})-[r*2..3]-(node1)-[b:%2$s]->(node2) %4$s return *
```

I have %4$s there for me to put whatever clauses I need to. If I want to have it as

```
WHERE node1.nodeId= {someNodeId} SET b= {props}
```

is that possible??

Also when I'm doing a transaction SET node={props} does not seem to work. I tried

```
statements:[
  {
    "statement":"..... SET node={props}",
    "parameters":{
      "props": {
        "description":"some description"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Any suggestions?? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot parameterize labels since the query plan might look different for a different label.

Parameterizing multiple properties using a map is possible, note the slight difference in the `SET` syntax:

```
{
  "query": "MATCH ..... SET node = {props}"
  "params": {
    "props":{
      "prop1:":"Property Name",
      .... 
    }
  }
}
```

Not 100% about `MERGE` but I guess this should work:

```
{
  "query": "MERGE (n:Label {identifier: {idValue}) ON CREATE SET n = {props}"
  "params": {
    "identifier": 123,
    "props":{
      "identifier": 123,
      "prop1:":"Property Name",
      .... 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan, setting multiple properties definitely work with that query. I'll try the MERGE like you have suggested!

Comment: Can this be done is a way it's not a all or nothing? I just want to update one property but by doing Set node ={props} if I set one property all the parameters gets over written. :(

Comment: using `SET n += {props}` overrides existing properties and addes new ones - leaving others untouched.

Comment: Hey Stefan, I get an error saying 'Invalid input \'+\': expected whitepace, comment........'. My query is: "Match (a:%1$s { value:{value} })-[:%2$s]->(b) where (b:%3$s) SET b += {props}"

Answer (score 0):

I found out!

```
CREATE  ...  SET node = {props}
```

does the trick to set multiple properties with parameters

doc: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/cypher-parameters.html