# The neo4j documentation says that unmanaged extensions are dangerous. I want to know how?

Tags: neo4j

The neo4j documentation [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html)

says that unmanaged extensions can be dangerous but does not explain how . Any examples or cases to explain how it may be dangerous would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tip, as you guess, lies in the name: *unmanaged*.

Unmanaged extensions are very powerful and allow you to deploy **arbitrary** code, such as those very bad things (the list is ***not*** exhaustive):

- `System.exit`
- security loopholes (like unchecked HTTP request parameters allowing [Cypher injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316583/injection-concerns-for-cypher-over-rest) for instance)
- thread-unsafe code
- inefficient Cypher queries/traversals (`PROFILE` might help troubleshooting with Cypher)
- highly garbage-producing code (e.g. creating many orphan objects in a giant Java for-each loop)

Simple example regarding the last point:

```
// do not do this at home
String foo = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    foo += String.valueOf(i);
}
```

This is of course both very naive and possible. Again, you can deploy arbitrary code and could end up in such a situation where the heap of your Neo4j instances gets polluted because of inefficient code defined in one of the active unmanaged extensions.

Indeed, unmanaged extensions directly impact your Neo4j instance(s) as they share the same server and environment. That is why you must be careful when using such a feature (and by careful, I just mean: monitor).

Comment: Regarding third point . I am looking for a more detailed explanation for example if I create execution engine and reuse it for all calls made to this web-service how does that impact garbage collection. Also   any memory allocated should be deallocated when the request is over so how would that be dangerous.

Comment: Well, using ExecutionEngine as a singleton is the way to go, so there should be no problems (though: always measure).
However, Garbage Collection cycles are decorrelated from HTTP request ones. I'll edit my answer regarding the last point.

Comment: So you are saying these local variable will not be garbage collected once the control moves out of the method ?

Comment: I'm saying they will be *eventually* garbage-collected. You just cannot control when.