# neo4j match node with an unknown list of properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, cypher

I am dynamically building a graph using `merge` to avoid creating duplicates. I have a query like:

```
`MERGE(a:${node.type} {id:'${node.id}', label:'${node.label}'}) SET a += $att RETURN a`, {att:node.attributes}
```

So I know the type, id, and label of the node I am adding but there is also an unknown list of attributes as well. I do not know the length of the list, or the keys in the list. I need to `merge` on the full list of attributes, but the way I currently have my query the node's attributes get rewritten every time a node matches the type, id, and label.

I have also tried:

```
 MERGE(a:${mergedObject.type} $node) RETURN a`, {node: mergedObject}
```

which fails with `Neo4jError: Parameter maps cannot be used in MERGE patterns`

How do I match a node on an unknown list of properties (length / keys)? I am using [neo4j-driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/neo4j-driver) module. I need the entire node and all of its properties to be unique.

Comment: What should uniquely define a node? Is `id` enough? You need to identify which properties in particular uniquely define the node, then ONLY merge on those properties, then set the remaining properties (or use ON MATCH SET and ON CREATE SET if there should be different behavior depending on whether the MERGE resulted in matching to something already existing or if it had to create the node)

Comment: @InverseFalcon, the whole node should be unique, including every attribute inside of it.

Comment: @Jordan.J.D Sure, the entire set of properties may be unique per node, but you can probably ignore many properties and still identify a specific node using just a minimal set of properties (ideally, just one).

Comment: @cybersam, maybe I am doing something odd but in my case I have a set of unknown properties that need to be unique. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

`MERGE` requires you to hardcode the names of the properties you want to use, so there is no way to dynamically provide the properties to a `MERGE`.

Your node.js code *could* dynamically generate the `MERGE` query, though. But you have to be careful to write your node.js code in a way that avoids Cypher [code injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316583/injection-concerns-for-cypher-over-rest). One way to avoid code injection is to generate hardcoded property names but pass every property value as a [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/).